# How to define Max and Min value of CFIndex?

Tags: ios, macros, core-foundation

I try to define a macro like this:

```
#import <CoreFoundation/CFBase.h>

#if __LLP64__
#define CFIndexMax LONG_LONG_MAX;
#define CFIndexMin LONG_LONG_MIN;
#else
#define CFIndexMax LONG_MAX;
#define CFIndexMin LONG_MIN;
#endif
```

But Xcode always warn me has no define of  `__LLP64_` which is conditional defined in  `CFBase.h`.

Comment: I Tried your code and I dont get any warnings. What are your project specifications?

Comment: Target on  iPhone 6s simulator@DejanSkledar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are checking the **value** of `__LLP64__` but you want to check for the **existence** of `__LLP64__`:

```
#ifdef __LLP64__
#define CFIndexMax LONG_LONG_MAX
#define CFIndexMin LONG_LONG_MIN
#else
#define CFIndexMax LONG_MAX
#define CFIndexMin LONG_MIN
#endif
```

However, only Windows uses the LLP64 model. Are you planning to build this code on Windows? If not, you should simplify your code by eliminating the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the *compiler* defines `__LLP64__` (or more likely `__LP64__`).
If you take a look at the `CFBase.h` pre-processor logic again, you'll see it forcibly defines `__LLP64__` when compiling for a 64-bit Windows target:

```
#if defined(__WIN64__) && !defined(__LLP64__)
#define __LLP64__ 1
#endif
```

<sup>Copyright (c) 1998-20016 Apple Inc.</sup>

If you're concerned about the size of `CGFloat` (or even `CFIndex` types on macOS, take a look at `CGBase.h` to see how things are defined:

```
#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
#define CGFLOAT_TYPE double
#define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
#define CGFLOAT_MIN DBL_MIN
#define CGFLOAT_MAX DBL_MAX
#else
#define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
#define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 0
#define CGFLOAT_MIN FLT_MIN
#define CGFLOAT_MAX FLT_MAX
#endif
```

<sup>Copyright (c) 2000-2011 Apple Inc.</sup>

You can conditionally define your max and min `CFIndex`es based on the boolean value of `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE`, which is not changing any time soon.

---

Lastly, I believe Windows is the only OS whose size of `long` types are 32 bits in a 64-bit runtime (that is, compared to linux and macOS which are 64 bits in a 64-bit runtime).

If you're *sure* you're switching on the right define, always check if the variable be defined first in the pre-compiler:

```
#if defined(__LLP64__) & __LLP64__
// conditionally define more stuff
#endif
```